# How to finish all the process and print out the message in async nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I trying to run huge array of urls with nodejs **async.eachSeries**. I want to show success msg after process done. But here in my code the success msg just come out before all the process complete. Please take a look at my code:

```
    var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    mysql =  require('mysql'),
    async = require('async');

    carlistrequest=request.defaults({
        headers: {
            'User-Agent':'request'
        }
    });
var callUrls =[
'http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2625750/2006-mercedes-benz-s350-amg-w221-full-loan.html',
'http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2625770/2010-toyota-estima-2-4-aeras-unregister-full-loan.html',
'http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2625739/2012-honda-city-1-5-e-facelift-full-loan.html',
'http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2536923/2002-bmw-318i-e46-2-0-cash-only-012-634-6341.html',
'http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2625567/-loan-up-to-rm43k-2009-toyota-vios-1-5-j-spec-a-trd-bodykit-2015-final-clear-stock-hurry-up-.html'
];
async.eachSeries(callUrls, function(uri, next){
    carlistrequest(uri, function(err, response, body){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var data={
            name: $('#main-sidebar').find('.sub').text()
        }
        console.log(data);
    })
    next();
},function(callback){
    console.log('All Url Done');
})
```

How to run url one by one and after all urls finish running, just show success msg. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `next()` inside the callback of your request.

```
async.eachSeries(callUrls, function (uri, next) {
    carlistrequest(uri, function (err, response, body) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var data = {
            name: $('#main-sidebar').find('.sub').text()
        }
        console.log(data);
        next();               // <<<<<<<<<<<<
    })
}, function (callback) {
    console.log('All Url Done');
});
```

`next()` tells async when the `function(uri, next)` is done with one url, if you call it outside your request's callback, you don't wait the request to be finished.

Another side effect, in your code, the iteration is not done in series like it should when you call `eachSeries()`, multiple requests are running at the same time. If you have hundreds of urls to request, you'd be banned from the server you're querying.

Comment: ShanShan;Yes like you said now I am facing this problem with hundreds of urls. I am new to nodejs async. Can u please show me sth?

Comment: Your code has the problem but moving `next()` to the right place solves it. Only one request will be issued at a time and when it's done, `next()` is called to tell async it's ok to move on the next url. However, it might take a lot of time to process all the urls, you should process batch of urls (maybe 5 or 10) instead of one url at a time.

Comment: @ ShanShan; I really don't know how to run 5 or 10 urls at a time. Please please explain me more

Comment: Create an array of 5 urls arrays. `async.eachSeries()` this array. inside the callback of  `eachSeries()`, do a `async.each()` (it will run all requests at once) on the 5 urls array you get. Inside the callback of `each()` do your request as needed. A quick code showing the structure: https://jsbin.com/fiqilegere/1/edit?js You can create the array of urls programmatically from your original array.

Comment: @ ShanShan, Thank you so much:)

Comment: @ ShanShan; Can u please show me how to select data from database? please see my code connection.query('SELECT * FROM urls LIMIT 3',function(err, rows){
 var array = rows;
 async.eachSeries(array, function(uri, next){
  console.log('i will go this'+uri);
  next();
 }, function(callback){
  console.log('All Url Done');
 })

Comment: the out put like this  i will go this[object Object]
i will go this[object Object]
i will go this[object Object]
All Url Done

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(uri)`. You should post a new question next time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `next()` call needs to be inside the `carlistrequest` callback, not beside it

I'm guessing `carlistrequest` is asynchronous (given it takes a callback)... so you fire off the async request then immediately tell `async.eachSeries` that this iteration is complete (but it's not - it still has work to do.)